# Error en poner FK en tabla

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema con mi Base de Datos. Intento poner una FK en mi tabla general que esta como PK en mi tabla Tarifas, intente de la siguiente manera y me marca el siguiente error.

> Tabla donde tengo la PK

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tabla donde quiero la PK (ya tengo el atributo pero no lo puede poner
>   como FK)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este query queria poner el atributo como FK pero me marca el siguiente error.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE general ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_tarifa) REFERENCES tarifas(id_tarifa);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: Hola, este error se puede dar por varias razones. Puedes correr este query SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; para ver más detalles sobre el error especifico y ver como lo resolvemos. Saludos desde Costa Rica.

Comment: La base de datos tiene muchos detalles, es por eso que la he estado modificando y por el momento tengo ese error

Comment: Corrí el query y me marco varias cosas.

Comment: 2018-11-26 10:12:12 7f0 Error in foreign key constraint of table asteriskcdrdb/#sql-14e4_2:
FOREIGN KEY (id_tarifa) REFERENCES tarifas(id_tarifa):
Cannot resolve table name close to:
(id_tarifa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablas de prueba:
(lo que si tendrias que fijarte los registros, como comentas las tablas tienen datos, si queres hacer que id_tarifa sea fk y en general tenes un id_tarifa pero en la tabla tarifa ese id no existe va a dar error porque no va a encontrar la clave foranea)

```
        use prueba;

        create table tarifa(
            id_tarifa int not null auto_increment,
            proveedor nvarchar(50) not null,
            desc_tar nvarchar(50) not null,
            primary key (id_tarifa)
        );

        create table general(
            id_general int not null auto_increment,
            nombre nvarchar(50) not null,
            id_tarifa int not null,
            primary key (id_general),
            FOREIGN KEY (id_tarifa)
            REFERENCES tarifa (id_tarifa)
        );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora creandola sin FK y usando la linea que pasas vos tambien funciona:

```
        use prueba;

        create table tarifa(
            id_tarifa int not null auto_increment,
            proveedor nvarchar(50) not null,
            desc_tar nvarchar(50) not null,
            primary key (id_tarifa)
        );

        create table general(
            id_general int not null auto_increment,
            nombre nvarchar(50) not null,
            id_tarifa int not null,
            primary key (id_general)
        );


        ALTER TABLE general ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_tarifa) REFERENCES 
        tarifa(id_tarifa)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si las tablas tienen datos para poder crear la FK necesitas que esten todos los datos, mira el siguiente ejemplo, creo la tabla sin FK cargo dos datos en general y uno solo en tarifa, uno de los datos en general hace referencia a la tarifa 2 pero esta no existe en la tabla tarifa, ahora ejecuto el comando para hacer las FK y ahi me da error no me daje por que no encuentra todas las referencias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Proba esta consulta (amoldala a los nombres exactos de tus tablas)

```
SELECT G.id_general, T.id_tarifa from GENERAL G LEFT JOIN TARIFA T ON 
T.id_tarifa = g.id_tarifa
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi ejemplo me muestra que existen dos registros pero para el registro dos no existe la tarifa dos, ahi esta el error en mi ejemplo

Comment: y como lo hago sin crear nuevamente las tablas?

Comment: Fijate que ahi subi que ejecutando el mismo comando que vos pasas funciona, proba fijandote si los id_tarifa que estan en general estan en la tabla tarifa, si tenes alguno en general que no esta en tarifa para prueba crea el el registro en tarifa con el id y ponele sin datos o cualquier cosa una vez hecho eso volve a probar la FK (Si paso eso... perdiste datos)

Comment: Ahi agregue el ejemplo a la respuesta de lo que te comento

Comment: Ahi subi una consulta con join para que verifiques que id te faltan en tarifa para ver si ese es el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias, claro olvide que tiene que terner los datos

Comment: No es necesario que tenga los datos, pero si la tabla ya tiene datos es necesario que esten todos los datos y las relaciones, un gusto haberte ayudado.